# Encountered a problem of creating a function for my little project

Tags: python, function

Currently I'm making a project and I want to add a function to it. But I have no clue about the problem I encountered recently. So, here's the wrong code of the function I wrote:

```
user_input = input()

while True:
    if user_input == "add_1":
        print("Start adding your #1 note...")
        content_1 = input("Please enter content: ")
    elif content_1 != '':
            print("You have added the #1 note. Please use other functions.")
            user_input = input()

    if user_input == "add_2":
        print("Start adding your #2 note...")
        content_2 = input("Please enter content: ")
    elif content_2 != '':
            print("You have added the #2 note. Please use other functions.")
            user_input = input()

    if user_input == "add_3":
        print("Start adding your #3 note...")
        content_3 = input("Please enter content: ")
    elif content_3 != '':
            print("You have added the #3 note. Please use other functions.")
            user_input = input()
```

The expected result:
When the user input the string 'add_1',
the system will process:

> Start adding your #1 note...
> (Next line) Please enter content: (e.g. Write something here)

Then, the content the user input will be stored into the variable 'content_1'.

Next, after the variable 'content_1' is NOT EMPTY, when the user input the string 'add_1', the system will print the message, 'You have added the #1 note. Please use other functions.'

The system will do the similar function according to the other input 'add_2' and 'add_3'.

The situation now is that I can't think of a solution to write a suitable code for the function. Can some programming masters help me with this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You can't access the variable that's assigned in the `if` block in its `elif` statement, because that condition isn't executed when the `if` condition is true.

Comment: You should have separate loops validating each input.

Answer (score 0):

The code is messy and hard to read, I would suggest sketching out a [diagram](https://images.app.goo.gl/1sxuaL4U9JjZ5hjGA) of how the logic should work out before even opening the computer and writing your first line of code.

The problem lies within the nested if/elif statements. For each option (`"add_1"`, `"add_2"`, `"add_3"`) there should be a `while` loop which should run for as long as the `content_1` is not empty. After the inner loop finishes, the outer loop restarts.

The code should look something like this. Other options should work the same way.

```
while True:
    # take user input at the start of the loop
    user_input = input()

    # option 1
    if user_input == "add_1":
        print("Start adding your #1 note...")
        content_1 = input("Please enter content: ")

        # while content_1 is '', ask again
        while content_1 == '':
            print("Start adding your #1 note...")
            content_1 = input("Please enter content: ")

        print("You have added the #1 note. Please use other functions.")

    # similarly for other options
    elif user_input == "add_2":
        # ...
```

Further reading:

- In some cases the newly added `walrus operator (:=)` can be useful when checking user input.
  For more information visit [this](https://realpython.com/lessons/assignment-expressions/) tutorial

Answer (score 0):

> content_1 is not defined till here if you meant user_input change content_1 to >user_input:
>
> > elif content_1 != '':
> >
> > > > print("You have added the #1 note. Please use other functions.")
> > > > user_input = input()

you have similar multiple mistakes

> if/elif statement must have else statement at last:

> > if (CONDITION):
> >
> > > > STATEMENTS
> > > > elif (CONDITION):
> > > > STATEMENTS
> > > > else:
> > > > STATEMENTS

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do but let's try to find a solution

```py
while True:
    user_input = input('What function do you want to use: ')

    if user_input == "add_1":
        print("Start adding your #1 note…")
        content_1 = input("Please enter content: ")
        if content_1 != '':
            print("You have added the #1 note. Please use other functions.")
    elif user_input == "add_2":
        print("Start adding your #2 note…")
        content_2 = input("Please enter content: ")
        if content_2 != '':
            print("You have added the #2 note. Please use other functions.")
    elif user_input == "add_3":
        print("Start adding your #3 note…")
        content_3 = input("Please enter content: ")
        if content_3 != '':
            print("You have added the #3 note. Please use other functions.")
```

But we could simplify this solution:

```
content = {}

while True:
    user_input = input('What function do you want to use: ')

    if user_input.startswith("add_") and len(user_input) == 5:
        note_number = user_input[4]
        if note_number in ('1', '2', '3'):
            print(f"Start adding your #{note_number} note…")
            content[note_number] = input("Please enter content: ")
            if content[note_number]:
                print(f"You have added the #{note_number} note. Please use other functions.")
```

Is that you wanted to do?